# Why is this VLOOKUPfunction returning error?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, vlookup, analysis

in the first image i used the **VLookup** function to get rate of pay of the employees from the spreadsheet. I attempt to use the same **VLookup** function to get the employee hour from the spreadsheet, i am getting #REF as result. What am i doing wrong?

[image: first attempt]

my attempt

[image: my attempt]

Comment: Instead of the column index of the return range, you type `B2` which equals 25 (dollar). You probably need to widen the range and use 3 or more for the indexed column. You probably need something like `=Vlookup(a2,'sheet'!$A$2:$C$5,3,0)`

Answer (score 1):

The third argument in the image "my attempt" shows "B2".

This should be "2" if you want the result from  the second column of the array.

One way of testing is to put "1" in the 3rd argument to see if you get the name returned.

Comment: I didn't know how i made that mistake. Thank you for pointing it out for me.